# Adding new data source connection only contains sql server in dropdown in SSRS 2016

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2016

I just installed SQL Server 2016 Express and was going to add an ODBC connection to my SSRS instance. When I went to the dropdown to change the connection type from SQL Server to DB2, the only connection type available in the dropdown is SQL Server.

Anyone know how to fix this? Is this a limitation in the Express version?

Answer (score 1):

It is a [limitation that you are hitting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281020(v=sql.105).aspx) for Reporting Services in SQL Server Express

> Report data sources must be SQL Server relational databases that run locally in SQL Server Express.

Comment: The link is for 2008 R2. Is there any documentation for 2016?

Comment: It remains the same for 2016.